# ionic2 - call parent or root component function

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using `ionic2` sidemenu template to build my app which I have:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Home;
  ...
  public callFromChild(){///<-- called by child component home.ts
    console.log("called from child component");
  }
```

and I want to call `callFromChild()` function from its `child component` which is **not** at the state of `push()` or `pop()`

**home.ts**

```
export class Home {
  ...
  callParent(){
  this.navCtrl.parent.callFromChild();
  }
```

and I got the error:

> error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Error in ./Home class Home - inline
>   template:28:45 caused by: Cannot set property 'callFromChild()' of null

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `this.navCtrl.parent` resolves to null, so you're trying to call a property on a null value. Have you correctly included `navCtrl`?

```
// import navCtrl for use in component
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
```